# What is the order of the operators given below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=10
print("Value is:",a//5*10%a^2+100-a)
```

I put this code as it is and got the value as `92`.

But if I solve this by directly putting a=10 in the equation, I'm getting 110.

Comment: As an exercise, put brackets in to seperate your idea of how the precedence works and to show how you came to a value of 110. Then, have a look at this table showing precedence: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm.

Comment: See: [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) from the Python docs.

Comment: `^` is probably not doing what you think it is doing; did you mean `**`? The result is 110 in that case.

Comment: Do you mean you are working out the solution on paper? If so, you aren't doing the correct operation for `^`; `print("Value is:",10//5*10%10^2+100-10)` also outputs 92.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a=10
print("Value is:",a//5*10%a^2+100-a)
```

Break down the expression:

```
a//5*10%a^2 + 100-a

100-a=90
```

`//` and `*` have same precedence, so go left to right.

```
(a//5)=2
```

`*` and `%` have same precedence, so go left to right.

```
2*10=20
```

you'll end up with `20%10^2`

```
20%10=0
0^2=2
```

hence, the expression becomes `90+2=92`

Comment: Thank you. I think I confused myself between ^ and **.